# Existence of Embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure how to solve the following task

Let $K\subset L_{0} \subset L$ be a tower field extension, $L$ is algebraic over $L_{0}$ and $K\subset E$ is a field extension, $E$ is the algebraic closure of $K$. Let $\theta_{0} : L_{0} \to E$ be an embedding over K.

Show that there exists an embedding $\theta : L \to E$ over $\theta_{0}$.

These are the definitions which we used in the lecture but it doesn't make sense to me:

A field extension of a field $K$ is a ring homomorphism $a: K \to N$, $N$ is also a field.

Let $K,M$ be fields. The  ring homomorphism $b: K \to M$ is called embedding.

Let $b: K \to M$ and $c:K \to L$ be two embeddings then the ring homomorphism $d: L\to M$ with $d\circ b=c$ is called embedding over $c$.

$c$ is an embedding over $K$ if the two embeddings $b: K \to M$ and $c:K \to L$  satisfy $K\subset M$ and $K\subset L$.

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Edit: Definitions

Comment: As you've formulated it, this isn't true. For all you know, $\theta_0$ may be surjective and $L/L_0$ not trivial.

Comment: I'll ask my professor if there's a missing condition, thank you

Comment: Ah, no sorry. I had missed the fact that $E$ is not *any* extension, but an algebraic closure of $K$. Then, it's ok.

Comment: That was my bad, I just edited that. Sorry about that